# How to access 7 day and per hour OpenWeatherMap data?

Tags: javascript, api, weather-api

I'm creating a weather app using the **openweathermap** API.

If the user enters the site then show the weather data of 7 days in the form of cards.

But if the user clicks on one card of weather then show the data of the particular day per hour.

To get 7 days of data I'm using this code:

```js
axios
    .get(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={CITY_NAME},{COUNTRY_CODE}&appid={API_KEY}&cnt=7"
    )
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.data);
    });
```

From this I'm getting the 7 day data. But how can I get per day/hour data using this API?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://openweathermap.org/api/hourly-forecast) you need to call the endpoint at `forecast/hourly` to get hourly weather data.